# Why won't my nav bar center?

Tags: html, css, nav, centering

So I've got my navbar set up pretty close to the way I'd like it to look, but for some reason it won't go to the center of my page. I've tried putting text-align: center; on most of the different elements that make up my nav bar, but it won't go no matter what I do. What am I doing wrong?

```css
.navbar {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: solid #000;
  border-width: 1.5px 0;
  list-style: none;
  height: 25px;
  width: 1000px;
}
.navbar a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 10px;
  border-bottom: 10px;
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
  font-size: 19px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner">
  <h1>Brian Funderburke Photography &amp; Design</h1>
  <div class="nav">
    <ul class="navbar">
      <li><a href="home.html">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="photo.html">Photography</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="design.html">Design</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="about.html">About</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: Which browser are you using? And put text-align: center; only on ".navbar", the other elements are taking it from ".navbar"

Comment: If I use your code I cannot see your problem. The navigation is centered.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to provide a web address of your website?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `.banner` width to 100% and then set `.nav` to center:

```
.banner{width: 100%;}
.nav{text-align: center;}
```

See fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/c51kr3jo/

Answer (score 1):

How I fix this problem usually is by following 3 steps:

1. Adding a full-width or a big width to the navbar container (.nav div in your case)
2. Adding a width to the navbar (usually try to find a width that will fit the most elements)
3. Adding `margin: 0 auto` to the navbar (this will center align the .navbar div)

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/gmj2775j/) is a jsfiddle I've created. Hope it helps.

Comment: Great. I'm glad it worked out for you ;) I've faced this issue many times and this is how I'm doing it always. But it might be a better way, so keep on learning! :)

Answer (score 1):

I added

```
.nav {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Which I got from [this](https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/) AMAZING article.

http://jsfiddle.net/abalter/44w7b73f/

Answer (score 1):

#### navbar center

```css
.navbar {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: solid #000;
  border-width: 1.5px 0;
  list-style: none;
  height: 25px;
  width: 1000px;
}
.navbar a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 10px;
  border-bottom: 10px;
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
  font-size: 19px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

/* center */
.nav1 {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;

  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;  

  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;

  width: 100%;
  height: auto;  
  
  text-align: center;  
}

.navbar1 {    

  -webkit-align-self: center;       
  align-self: center;
}

li a:hover {
  color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}
/* || center */
```

```html
<div class="nav1">
  <h1>Brian Funderburke Photography &amp; Design</h1>
</div>
<div class="nav nav1"> 
  <ul class="navbar navbar1">
    <li><a href="home.html">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="photo.html">Photography</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="design.html">Design</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="about.html">About</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Your code appears to already be working from what I can tell (though you were missing a closing `</div>` in your example). Make sure your CSS is being properly imported and applied.

Here is a working example to prove it is looking okay: http://jsfiddle.net/611mbvtu/